# Remove country borders in maps::map("world", ...) in R

Tags: r, maps

I'm looking for a world map using `map()` from the `maps` package showing land only, to plot lines over. I've tried various combinations of arguments, but am always left with country borders. Setting `lwd=0` for example throws the message `invalid value specified for graphical parameter "lwd"`, and the below shows this image - thin country borders, but still present.

```
map("world", col="#151515", fill=T, bg="#000000", interior=F, lwd=0.02)
```

[image]

Comment: if `map` function wasn't a requirement, you might want to change the question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
plot(world, col="gray", border="gray", bg="black")
```

For more graphic polygon options, see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36877/how-do-i-change-the-polygon-fill-color-and-border-color-for-spatialpolygons-obje)

Comment: I was afraid I didn't answer your question using the desired function: `map` doesnt seem to allow changing of the boundary lines color, and although you _could_ conceivably dissolve a `world` polygon and morph it to the "geographical database" format that `map` requires, it's not the easy way...

Comment: Setting the `border` to the same color as `col` worked (didn't realize that argument existed - undocumented so must inherit from polygons), so I consider your answer valid. Edited for more specificity to my problem though, hope that's alright.

Comment: I know that `plot` method for SpatialPolygons-class takes `border` as an argument... but when I try it your way with the `map` function, I get `"border" is not a graphical parameter` error. Why is that?